# Extract variable from subexpression

Tags: expression-manipulation

I have an expression of the form `a1*x*b1^2 + a2*y*c1^2` I want to extract the `x` and `y` from the expressions. `a_, b_, and c_` are the only types of variables that appear in the expression . Form of `x` and `y` are not known. Anyone know how? `x` and `y` are not necessarily numbers .

Comment: I tried exp/a[#]/;MemberQ[exp,a[#], Infinity]&Range[3]. But it did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
f[expr_] := Module[
  {vars = Variables[Level[expr, {-1}]]},
  vars = Pick[vars,
    Switch[#, "a" | "b" | "c", True, _, 
       False] & /@
     (StringTake[ToString[#], 1] & /@ vars)];
  ((CoefficientList[expr, vars] // Flatten) /. 
     (0 :> Nothing))[[1]]]

expr1 = a1*x*b1^2 + a2*y*c1^2;

f /@ (List @@ expr1)

(*  {x, y}  *)

expr2 = a1*2*b1^2 + a2*y*c1^2;

f /@ (List @@ expr2)

(*  {2, y}  *)
```

Note that Mathematica may alter the form of an expression from what is manually entered

```
expr3 = a1*(y^2 + 2 x)*b1^2 + a2*y*c1^2

(*  a2 c1^2 y + a1 b1^2 (2 x + y^2)  *) 

f /@ (List @@ expr3)

(*  {y, 2 x + y^2}  *)
```

Comment: thanks a lot. It took me while to look up the commands but I understand it now. Thanks a lot.